# How to add a date column with a condition?

Tags: python

I have a time series with daily values. I have extracted the month values in column L. I want to add a column (M) with date format. The first value of column ‘M’ is year 2000. I want the value 2000 is repeated if the month is the same, and when we go to the next month the value 2000 becomes 2001 and so on.
[image: Dataset]

This can be done easily in excel by this conditional code:

```
=IF(L3=L2,M2,M2+366)
```

But I don’t know how to do that in python.

Comment: this looks like a spreadsheet to me - are you trying to work in it or are you relying on a Python library?

Comment: I have done it in excel. But now I need to do that in Python. columns A to L are available and I want to generate column M in python.

Comment: We'd need to see how you represent this data in Python before there can be any Python answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A code gives you output which you want:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import datetime
#initial date
m2 = datetime.date(2000, 1, 1)
#get the Book1 excel in python
wb1 = load_workbook('Book1.xlsx')
#select first sheet of the excel
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]
#get max row of the excel
MAXROW = ws1.max_row
#loop and apply your function =IF(L3=L2,M2,M2+366) in python 
for i in range(2,MAXROW+1):
    month = ws1.cell(row=i, column=12).value
    monthofnextrow = ws1.cell(row=i+1, column=12).value
    if monthofnextrow==month:
        ws1.cell(row=i, column=13).value = m2
    else:
        m2 = m2+datetime.timedelta(days=366)
        ws1.cell(row=i, column=13).value = m2
#save the excel file
wb1.save()
```

Let me know if this helps you

Comment: Thank you. I used your code to solve my problem. here is the code that I wrote. Is it possible to write this code by using List comprehension?

Comment: Any special reason to use [List comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) because some time it become complex and has not any plus points.

Answer (score 0):

```
m2 = datetime.date(2000, 1, 1)
y = [m2]
for i in range(0,len(df)-1):
    month = df['month'].iat[i]
    monthofnextrow =df['month'].iat[i+1]
    if monthofnextrow==month:
        y.append(m2)
    else:
        m2 = m2+datetime.timedelta(days=366)
        y.append(m2)
df["yearf"] = y
```